# Drag and drop issue with Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, drag-and-drop

I am trying to implement a drag-and-drop using JavaScript. It works perfectly in Firefox, but the drop does not work well in Chrome. The dragged file cannot be dropped easily on the defined area.
Here's my code:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".drop_zone__input").forEach(inputElement = \ > {
  const dropzoneElement = inputElement.closest(".drop_zone");

  dropzoneElement.addEventListener("click", e => {
    inputElement.click();
  });

  inputElement.addEventListener("change", e => {
    if (inputElement.files.length) {
      updateThumbnail(dropzoneElement, inputElement.files[0]);
    }
  });

  dropzoneElement.addEventListener("dragover", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dropzoneElement.classList.add("drop_zone__over");
  });

  ["dragleave", "dragend"].forEach(type => {
    dropzoneElement.addEventListener(type, e => {
      dropzoneElement.classList.remove("drop_zone__over");
    });
  });

  dropzoneElement.addEventListener("drop", e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (e.dataTransfer.files.length) {
      inputElement.files = e.dataTransfer.files;
      updateThumbnail(dropzoneElement, e.dataTransfer.files[0]);
    }

    dropzoneElement.classList.remove("drop_zone__over");
  });

});


/**
* @param {HTMLElement} dropzoneElement

* @param {File} file
  */
function updateThumbnail(dropzoneElement, file) {
  let thumbnailElement = dropzoneElement.querySelector(".drop_zone__thumb");

  console.log(file);

  if (dropzoneElement.querySelector(".drop_zone_prompt")) {
    dropzoneElement.querySelector(".drop_zone_prompt").remove();
  }

  if (!thumbnailElement) {
    thumbnailElement = document.createElement("div");
    thumbnailElement.classList.add("drop_zone__thumb");
    dropzoneElement.appendChild(thumbnailElement);

  }

  thumbnailElement.dataset.label = file.name;

  if (file.type.startsWith("image/")) {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => {
      thumbnailElement.style.backgroundImage = `url('${reader.result}')`;
    };

  } else {
    thumbnailElement.style.backgroundImage = null;
  }
}
```

```css
.drop_zone {
  margin-left: 450px;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 25px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #cccccc;
  border: 4px dashed rgb(217, 51, 51);
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.drop_zone__over {
  border-style: solid;
}

.drop_zone__input {
  display: none;
}

.drop_zone__thumb {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.drop_zone__thumb::after {
  content: attr(data-label);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="drop_zone">
  <span class="drop_zone_prompt">Drag and drop your file here</span>

  <input type="file" name="myFile" class="drop_zone__input">
</div>
```

When the hover occurs with the dragged file on the drop area, a plus icon appears at the cursor. This happens in Firefox when you hover on any point on the area. However, in Chrome the plus icon only shows up rarely. What is wrong with my CSS code? Is it a JavaScript error? Or do I have do use a Chrome-specific CSS trick to work around this problem?

If I had known, I would not have asked here

Comment: You might have a problem here `.forEach(inputElement =\> {` should it not be `=>`

Comment: i turned your code into a snippet and as @CarstenLøvboAndersen tells you , your typo raises an error while running the snippet :)

Comment: I just copied that snippet and made the correction highlighted by @CarstenLøvboAndersen and it runs OK so this should be closed as a typo

Comment: Working fine now: https://codepen.io/billyBOB88/pen/poqEpXq